# MongoDB, Docker, Meteor: Connection Refused

Tags: mongodb, meteor, connection, docker

Meteor works perfectly if I run "meteor". If I setup MongoDB and run Meteor with MONGO_URL set to "mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/meteor" then it too works perfectly.  However, if I run a Docker Container that calls exactly the same Meteor files on the same machine with the MONGO_URL set as above then I get the error: "Exception in callback of async function: Error: failed to connect to [127.0.0.1:27017]".  Logic would state that the introduction of Docker is causing the problem.  Therefore, is there something I must do to specifically allow Meteor to call MongoDB from inside a container - such as something additional with the MongoDB ports etc.

Dockerfile is:

```
FROM ubuntu:14.04 

MAINTAINER Me "me@me.com" 

RUN apt-get update -y && apt-get install --no-install-recommends -y -q chrpath libfreetype6 libfreetype6-dev libssl-dev libfontconfig1 

RUN apt-get install --no-install-recommends -y -q build-essential ca-certificates curl git gcc make nano python 

ENV PATH /bin:/usr/local/sbin 

RUN curl install.meteor.com | sh 

ENV ROOT_URL 127.0.0.1 
ENV PORT 3000 
ENV MONGO_URL mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/meteor 

EXPOSE 3000 

CMD [ "meteor" ] 

RUN apt-get clean && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* /tmp/* /var/tmp/*
```

Meteor is called with the following:

```
docker run --name meteor-dev -it -p 3000:3000 -v /machine/meteor:/opt/meteor -w /opt/meteor meteor-dev
```

Comment: Meteor is called with the following:
docker run --name meteor-dev -it -p 3000:3000 -v /machine/meteor:/opt/meteor -w /opt/meteor meteor-dev

Comment: Dockerfile is:

FROM ubuntu:14.04
MAINTAINER Me "me@me.com"
RUN apt-get update -y && apt-get install --no-install-recommends -y -q chrpath libfreetype6 libfreetype6-dev libssl-dev libfontconfig1
RUN apt-get install --no-install-recommends -y -q build-essential ca-certificates curl git gcc make nano python
ENV PATH /bin:/usr/local/sbin
RUN curl https://install.meteor.com/ | sh
ENV ROOT_URL http://127.0.0.1
ENV PORT 3000
ENV MONGO_URL mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/meteor
EXPOSE 3000
CMD [ "meteor" ]
RUN apt-get clean && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* /tmp/* /var/tmp/*

Comment: Sorry about the messy Dockerfile but it is the only way they will let me post so I thought something was better than nothing...and I see that this field has ruined my ROOT_URL reference anyway :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you are running a container it creates its own network which is isolated from host network.
So when you are tying to connect to Mongo using "mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/meteor it searches for MongoDB inside your container.

Instead of using 127.0.0.1 use the host ip addresss or hostname.

Or if your MongoDB is running from a container create a link and use the link to start meteor container. Hope this helps